# How to find the difference between two java list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a string s1 = `Hooray In this case you know, you care you want to emphasize, that we won the match` and a string s2 = `Hooray ! In this case you know, you care you want to emphasize, that we won the match.`

As there is two difference in both the string s1 and s2
`!` and `.`

I tried a generic way to find the difference

```
     List<String> strings1 = Arrays.asList(s1.split("\\s+"));
     List<String> strings2 = Arrays.asList(s2.split("\\s+"));
     difference(strings2 ,strings1);
    public <T> List<T> difference(List<T> s2, List<T> s1) {
        List<T> toReturn = new ArrayList<>(s2);
        toReturn.removeAll(s1);
        return toReturn;
    }
```

From my logic the end result i am getting in list is `!` and `match.`, But I just want `!` and `.` exact difference

Is there any better approach for finding the difference between the list.

Comment: See [Finding the Differences Between Two Lists in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lists-difference)

Comment: This has nothing to do with lists. You want differences between [Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be splitting not only by spaces `\s+` but also by word boundary `\b`:

```java
String pattern = "\\s+|\\b";
List<String> strings1 = Arrays.asList(s1.split(pattern));
List<String> strings2 = Arrays.asList(s2.split(pattern));
System.out.println(strings2);
difference(strings2, strings1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
!
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `org.bitbucket.cowwoc.diffmatchpatch.DiffMatchPatch` to do the job for you. Just import the library to your project and do:

```
DiffMatchPatch dmp = new DiffMatchPatch();
LinkedList<DiffMatchPatch.Diff> diff = dmp.diffMain(s1, s2, false);
System.out.println(diff);
```

It prints the differences as `Diff` objects as follows:

```
[Diff(EQUAL,"Hooray "), Diff(INSERT,"! "), Diff(EQUAL,"In this case you know, you care you want to emphasize, that we won the match"), Diff(INSERT,".")]
```

So, to extract the differences, you can do:

```
for (DiffMatchPatch.Diff tokens: diff) {
    if (tokens.operation != DiffMatchPatch.Operation.EQUAL) {
        System.out.println(tokens.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but is there any other way to do as I don't want to use external library